# Return array of objects from VB6 to VB.NET using Interop

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, vb6, interop

I'm making a COM dll in .NET for use in VB6, the dll works fine in VB6.

but I have a problem when I want to assign arrays.

here is the **Person** class in VB.NET, the **Name** property is an **array** of the class called **Class2**

```
Public Class Person

  Private _name() As Class2

  Public Property Name() As Class2()
     Get
       Return Me._name
     End Get
     Set
       Me._name = value
     End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

This is the **Class2**:

```
Public Class Class2

  Private m_id As String

  Public Property id() As String
    Get
      Return m_id
    End Get
    Set
      m_id = Value
    End Set
  End Property

End Class
```

this is the code I'm using in VB6:

```
Dim vArray(2) As MyLib.Class2
vArray(0).id = "Hello 1"
vArray(1).id = "Hello 2"
vArray(2).id = "Hello 3"

Dim i As New MyLib.Person
i.Name = vArray ' here throws an error
```

Comment: What error do you get? Can we have the exact error message please?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 Dim vArray(2) As Class2
        For index = 0 To vArray.Length - 1
            vArray(index) = New Class2
            vArray(index).id = "Hello " + index.ToString
        Next
        Dim i As New Person
        i.Name = vArray
```

Comment: Please add an explanation as to what this does, and why you think it will solve the question. This answer is currently in the Low Quality queue.